# Alignment Problem with Angular Material Expansion Panel Header

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I am using Angular 14 Material Expansion Panel as below...

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <a mat-list-item role="listitem" class="list-item-setting" id="emailTemplatesId" matTooltipPosition="right"
    routerLinkActive="active">
    <mat-icon class="list-item-setting">email</mat-icon>
    <span class="nowrap">User 1</span>
  </a>
  <a>
    <mat-accordion>
      <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle [(expanded)]="panelOpenState">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-panel-title style="text-align: left">
            <mat-icon class="list-item-setting">email</mat-icon>
            <span class="list-item-setting">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;User 2</span>
          </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <div>
          <mat-panel-description class="mat-panel-description-setting"><a class="list-item-setting"
              routerLinkActive="active">Submenu 1</a></mat-panel-description>
          <mat-panel-description class="mat-panel-description-setting"><a class="list-item-setting"
              routerLinkActive="active">Submenu 2</a></mat-panel-description>
          <mat-panel-description class="mat-panel-description-setting"><a class="list-item-setting"
              routerLinkActive="active">Submenu 3</a></mat-panel-description>
        </div>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>
  </a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

The css code is below...

```
.list-item-setting {
    padding: 0!important;
    padding-left: 16px;
    color: $white;
}
```

The current output is as given below...

[image: Alignment Problem]

The current output seems to be good. If you notice the angular html code above, I have used `&nbsp;` 4 times to achieve this.

Is it possible to achieve the same output with padding for `User 2` in `css` to achieve the same result? I have used the same `list-item-setting` but could not succeed. This problem occurs when I use `mat-accordion`.

Comment: @RokBenko Could you please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `padding-left` didn't work because you didn't add `!important`.

If you change this...

```
.list-item-setting {
  padding: 0 !important;
  padding-left: 16px;
}
```

...to this...

```
.list-item-setting {
  padding: 0 !important;
  padding-left: 16px !important;
}
```

...you get this output.

[image: Screenshot 1]

But this is not what you want, I guess. As you can see, there's `padding-left` where it shouldn't be, and there's no `padding-left` where it should be. Why? You added the class `list-item-setting` to multiple elements. I suggest you add a specific class (e.g, `add-padding`) that will only add `padding-left`. Add this class to all elements you want to have the `padding-left`.

I guess you want to have `padding-left` on *User 1*, *User 2*, *Submenu 1*, *Submenu 2*, and *Submenu 3*. If you don't want to have it on any of these elements, just remove the class `add-padding` on that element.

**list-overview-example.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Basic list
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'list-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'list-overview-example.html',
})
export class ListOverviewExample {}
```

**list-overview-example.html**

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <a
    mat-list-item
    role="listitem"
    class="list-item-setting"
    id="emailTemplatesId"
    matTooltipPosition="right"
    routerLinkActive="active"
  >
    <mat-icon class="list-item-setting">email</mat-icon>
    <span class="nowrap add-padding">User 1</span>
  </a>
  <a>
    <mat-accordion>
      <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle>
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-panel-title style="text-align: left">
            <mat-icon class="list-item-setting">email</mat-icon>
            <span class="list-item-setting add-padding">User 2</span>
          </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <div>
          <mat-panel-description class="mat-panel-description-setting"
            ><a class="list-item-setting add-padding" routerLinkActive="active"
              >Submenu 1</a
            ></mat-panel-description
          >
          <mat-panel-description class="mat-panel-description-setting"
            ><a class="list-item-setting add-padding" routerLinkActive="active"
              >Submenu 2</a
            ></mat-panel-description
          >
          <mat-panel-description class="mat-panel-description-setting"
            ><a class="list-item-setting add-padding" routerLinkActive="active"
              >Submenu 3</a
            ></mat-panel-description
          >
        </div>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>
  </a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

**styles.scss**

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header {
  padding: 0 16px !important;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.add-padding {
  padding-left: 16px;
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Screenshot 2]

See the [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mxj4at?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist-overview-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Flist-overview-example.ts,src%2Fstyles.scss).

Comment: Excellent answer @RokBenko